# Why does Vue convert my single quotes to double quotes in my background-image url?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Every post I've found on this topic referts to using Vetur or Prettier. I'm using neither. This is a basic Vue CLI install. The only thing I've added is sass-loader. I've added my `package.json` to the bottom of the post to confirm what I'm actually using.

```
<template>
    <div class="hero-section" :style="{ backgroundImage: 'url(' + currentBgImage + ')' }">
        <i class="fa fa-chevron-left" @click="previousImage()"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-chevron-right" @click="nextImage()"></i>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'HeroSlider',
    props: {
      imageArray: Array
    },
    data() {
      return {
        selectedImage: 0,
      };
    },
    computed: {
      currentBgImage() {
        let array = this.imageArray;
        let result = array[this.selectedImage].image;
        return result;
      }
    },
```

The result is:

```
<div class="hero-section" style="background-image:url("/src/assets/image_1.jpg");">
    <i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
</div>
```

I've also tried including the quotes in the computed property's value and in the html but the result was the same:

```
:style="{ backgroundImage: 'url(\'' + currentBgImage + '\')'
```

Now, *something curious happened* as I copied this HTML from my inspection window. When I pasted it here it initially pasted like this with `&quot;` instead of `"`. Could that be an indicator of what's going wrong?

```
<div class="hero-section" style="background-image: url(&quot;/src/assets/image_1.jpg&quot;);">
    <i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
</div>
```

*package.json*

```
{
  "name": "heroslider",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.3.2",
    "vue": "^2.6.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^4.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^4.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^4.0.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.3",
    "eslint": "^5.16.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^5.0.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.13.0",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.0",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "rules": {
      "no-console": "off"
    },
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "babel-eslint"
    }
  },
  "postcss": {
    "plugins": {
      "autoprefixer": {}
    }
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Any chance you're using VScode with lint-on-save enabled?

Comment: No, I'm using PhpStorm.

Comment: I'm wondering if my filepath is wrong because it works fine if the computed property returns a URL, even with the double quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does Vue convert my single quotes to double quotes in my background-image url?

It doesn't.

See the following example, which isn't using any libraries at all:

```js
const el = document.getElementById('div')

el.style.backgroundImage = 'url(https://vuejs.org/images/logo.png)'

console.log(el.style.backgroundImage)
console.log(el.outerHTML)
```

```css
#div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="div"></div>
```

Notice that the console logging has `"` characters around the URL even though they didn't appear in the original value. Those are encoded to `&quot;` within the HTML, which is correct.

The browser is normalizing the value. It shouldn't make any difference to the URL that is requested from the server. If your image isn't loading the quotes are not the problem. That should be evident by checking the URL being used to load the image in the Network tab of your browser's developer tools.